# Pack pytest with pytest_html module using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pyinstaller, pytest-html

I am having an issue to pack pytest with pytest_html module to an executable using pyinstaller
On Windows.

When running it with Python it does work, but I need to pack it as exe.

My example code:

```
import pytest
import pytest_html

def test_hello():
    assert True

pytest.main(["-p", "pytest_html","-vvv", "--capture=tee-sys","--html=report.html", __file__])
```

Also Tied with
`pytest.main(["-vvv","--html=report.html", __file__], plugins=[pytest_timeout])`

The Pyinstaller command I am running is:
`pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --nowindow --exclude-module PyQt5  --log-level DEBUG -n py_exe file.py`

Also tried adding it as a hidden module with no luck.

The result I am getting is:
 `error: unrecognized arguments: --html=report.html`

Looking at Analysis-00.toc, I can see the module :
`('pytest_html', 'c:\\users\\nathan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pytest_html\\__init__.py', 'PYMODULE')`

Versions: Windows 10,
Python 3.8.3,
pytest 5.4.3,
pytest-html 2.1.1,
pyinstaller 3.6

---

EDIT:
Issue was fixed, see https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5016